# What is the probability?

Tags: math

If we have a room with a number of people and we know that the probability that a person has a phone is 30% p(B) = 30% and the probability that a person does not have a phone is 70% P(not B) = 70%, we choose 3 people,  What is the probability of event D: “that at least 1 person out of 3 has a phone” I want to calculate without the inverse event of D, and with this inverse event.

I tried p(D) = 0.3×0.7×0.7 + 0.3×0.3×0.7 + 0.3×0.3×0.3

Comment: This isn't a programming question, it's a maths question, best asked over on the [math.se] stackexchange site, but there (much like here) you're going to have to explain not just what you tried, but _why_ you did that, so that people can see you gave it a proper try instead of just offloading  your homework onto a bunch of professionals in the hopes they do your work for you.

Comment: That's not my homework, I just want to understand probabilities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simon's answer is the canonical way to do this, but if you must solve it without calculating the inverse, calculate the probability of k phones times the ways of allocating k phones for k >= 1.

For n people, k phones, p = probability of having a phone, then the probability that at least 1 person has a phone is:

```
choose(n, 1) * p^1 * (1-p)^(n-1) +
choose(n, 2) * p^2 * (1-p)^(n-2) +
... +
choose(n, n) * p^n * (1-p)^(n-n)
```

In your example, n=3, p=0.3, so we have:

```
choose(3,1) * (0.3)^1 * (0.7)^2 +
choose(3,2) * (0.3)^2 * (0.7)^1 +
choose(3,3) * (0.3)^3 * (0.7)^0
=
3 * 0.3 * 0.49 +
3 * 0.09 * 0.7 +
1 * 0.027 * 1
= 0.657
= 65.7%
```

So with a lot more work, we get the same answer as Simon.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I wanted, but a question, why do we multiply by choose, and here in our case, the order is not important?

Comment: While we don't care about order, we have to care about the number of ways something can happen. For example, there are three different ways that exactly 1 of 3 people can have a phone, each of which has a probability of 0.3*0.7*0.7.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the probability that none of the three have a phone...

```
P_0 = (0.7)^3
```

then the probability that at least one person has a phone must be...

```
1 - P_0
```

or as a percentage, 100*(1 - (0.7)^3) = 65.7

You say you want to also calculate the probability without using the 'inverse event' P_0. Adding probabilities P_1 + P_2 + P_3 is only a first order approximation to the actual probability of P_1 or P_2 or P_3 which only really works with decent accuracy if all the P_is are very small. I don't know how to calculate the result without using what you call the 'inverse event' or even if it's possible to do exactly.

Comment: Thanks, is there another way without using the inverse event [(I mean by the inverse event "P(not D)" like you did then P(D) = 1-P(not D)], but I want to calculate it with another method, if possible.